# Why main thread can't update UI elements inside a horizontallistview?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-asynctask

Last few days I'm trying to update some UI Views inside a custom [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/TomIsYourName/Android-HorizontalListView). I've been trying countless way like using Async Task, posting message via handler etc. I didn't figure out to update them. As a result, I tried to build a queue system to update them one by one. Here is my code and it's still not updating them.

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import roboguice.RoboGuice;
import CustomChannel;
import EGPInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EPGLoader {

    static private EPGLoader _instance;

    public static EPGLoader getInstance(Context context) {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new EPGLoader();
        }
        mContext = context;
        return _instance;
    }

    private HashMap<String, WeakReference<EPGChannel>> _cachedChannels;
    private Queue<EPGChannel> _queue;
    private EPGThread _thread;
    private static Context mContext;
    private boolean _isBusy;

    public EPGLoader() {
        _cachedChannels = new HashMap<String, WeakReference<EPGChannel>>();
        _queue = new LinkedList<EPGChannel>();
        _isBusy = false;
    }

    public void load(ArrayList<TextView> textViews, CustomChannel channel) {
        Iterator<EPGChannel> it = _queue.iterator();

        EPGChannel epgChannel = new EPGChannel();
        epgChannel.setChannel(channel);
        epgChannel.setTextViews(textViews);

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().equals(epgChannel)) {
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }

        _queue.add(epgChannel);
        loadNext();
    }

    private void loadNext() {
        Iterator<EPGChannel> it = _queue.iterator();
        if (!_isBusy && it.hasNext()) {
            _isBusy = true;
            EPGChannel epgChannel = it.next();
            it.remove();
            EPGChannel epgCache = get(epgChannel.getChannel().getChannelId());
            if (epgCache != null) {
                Log.i("A", "Cache");
                epgChannel.textViews.get(0).setText("1");
                epgChannel.textViews.get(1).setText("2");
                epgChannel.textViews.get(2).setText("3");
                epgChannel.textViews.get(3).setText("4");
                _isBusy = false;
                loadNext();
            } else {
                _thread = new EPGThread(epgChannel);
                _thread.start();
                Log.i("A", "Live");
            }
        }
    }

    private EPGChannel get(String channelId) {
        if (_cachedChannels.containsKey(channelId)) {
            return _cachedChannels.get(channelId).get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class EPGThread extends Thread {

        private EPGChannel EPGChannel;

        final Handler threadHandler = new Handler();
        final Runnable threadCallBack = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                onLoad();
            }
        };

        public EPGThread(EPGChannel epgChannel) {
            this.EPGChannel = epgChannel;
        }

        private void onLoad() {
            if (_thread != null) {
                EPGChannel epgChannel = _thread.EPGChannel;
//              epgChannel.getTextViews().get(1).setText(epgChannel.getChannel().getName());
                epgChannel.getTextViews().get(0).setText("1");
                epgChannel.getTextViews().get(1).setText("2");
                epgChannel.getTextViews().get(2).setText("3");
                epgChannel.getTextViews().get(3).setText("4");
            }
            _thread = null;
            _isBusy = false;
            loadNext();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                _isBusy = true;
                ChannelManager channelManager = RoboGuice.getInjector(mContext).getInstance(ChannelManager.class);
                ArrayList<EGPInfo> epgInfo = channelManager.getChannelEPG(EPGChannel.getChannel().getChannelId());
                if (epgInfo.size() == 2) {
                    EPGChannel.getChannel().updateEPGInformations(epgInfo.get(0), epgInfo.get(1));
                }
                if (!_cachedChannels.containsKey(EPGChannel.getChannel().getChannelId()))
                    _cachedChannels.put(EPGChannel.getChannel().getChannelId(), new WeakReference<EPGLoader.EPGChannel>(EPGChannel));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                threadHandler.post(threadCallBack);
            }
        }

    }

    private class EPGChannel {

        private ArrayList<TextView> textViews;
        private CustomChannel channel;

        public ArrayList<TextView> getTextViews() {
            return textViews;
        }

        public void setTextViews(ArrayList<TextView> textViews) {
            this.textViews = textViews;
        }

        public CustomChannel getChannel() {
            return channel;
        }

        public void setChannel(CustomChannel channel) {
            this.channel = channel;
        }

    }

}
```

I call it from main thread when getView event of ArrayAdapter fires.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View retval, ViewGroup parent) {

if (retval == null) {
    retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.channel_item, null);
}

final CustomChannel currentChannel = getItem(position);

final TextView nowTitle = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.channel_item_current_show_title);
final TextView nowPlayTime = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.channel_item_current_show_play_time);
final TextView nextTitle = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.channel_item_next_show_title);
final TextView nextPlayTime = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.channel_item_next_show_play_time); 

ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();
textViews.add(nowTitle);
textViews.add(nowPlayTime);
textViews.add(nextTitle);
textViews.add(nextPlayTime);

EPGLoader.getInstance(mContext).load(textViews, currentChannel);

return retval;

}
```

So, what is wrong with my codes? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I replace the HorizontalListView with normal Android's ListView and it works but I have to use HorizontalListView in the project.  Any suggesstions?

Edit 2: I reward to back (HorizontalListView) and tried to set Background color of some UI controllers, guess what? It updated. It doesn't update text property!!! Why????[image]

Comment: Some advice: you should use ViewHolder when you work with ListView in your getView() method. Also where is the return statement in your getView method?

Comment: retval variable is the return value @Marek ;)

Comment: You have to use "return" statement to return the value. In my getView method I am returning the created View by "return view;" retval is not return Value, it is just the old view to reuse. There was a tutorial on how to use getView() method properly. It was from google I/O presentation but I can't find it now... UPDATE - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA P.S I am having hard time to understand how this code is working on your machine without return statement...

Comment: of course there is a return value otherwise how can I compile the code :) I forgot paste it while cropping. @Marek

Comment: Edit you post please with an updated code ;)

Comment: Done. I added it. Can you check it @Marek? ;)

Comment: you could also add some screenshot or image on how it should look like and how does it look like

Comment: @Marek I listened your advice and just tried it and same again ... sorry ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31920/discussion-between-nesimtunc-and-marek)

Comment: @Marek in listView it works but it doesn't work inside this horizontallistview.

Comment: Well it is your implementation of HorizontalListView. I use default HorizontalScrollView but also there are some problems with it. Not sure if I can help you more...

Comment: This is caused by the UI control that I used. I found another HorizontalListView (https://github.com/nesimtunc/HorizontalVariableListView) and it works now without any changes.